# Как распарсить полученный ответ json

Tags: jquery, ajax

В jquery новичек, подскажите получаю ответ success ajax в формате json вид его такой

```
[{"id":1,"catalog_groups_id":1,"price_from":1000,"price_up_to":2000,"youtube":null,"photo":null,"more_photo":null,"tel":"","tel_work":null,"position":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":2,"catalog_groups_id":1,"price_from":1000,"price_up_to":2000,"youtube":null,"photo":null,"more_photo":null,"tel":"","tel_work":null,"position":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
```

Как распарсить вывести к примеру значение price_from в список и чтоб этот список выводился в div class ="menu"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    let Arr = [{"id":1,"catalog_groups_id":1,"price_from":1000,"price_up_to":2000,"youtube":null,"photo":null,"more_photo":null,"tel":"","tel_work":null,"position":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
        {"id":2,"catalog_groups_id":1,"price_from":1000,"price_up_to":2000,"youtube":null,"photo":null,"more_photo":null,"tel":"","tel_work":null,"position":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}];

    let div = document.getElementsByClassName('menu'); // Получаем элемент с классом menu
    let ul = document.createElement('ul'); // Создаём объект списка
    Arr.forEach(function (c) { // Перебираем массив
        let li = document.createElement('li'); // Для каждого элемента создаём элемент списка
        li.innerText = c.price_from; // Добавляем значение price_from в элемент
        ul.appendChild(li); // Добавляем элемент в объект списка
    });
    div[0].appendChild(ul); // Добавляем список в первый div(Если несколько их, то можно менть индекс) с классом menu
```

```html
<div class ="menu"></div>
```